# Portrait capture like iPhone x

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

How can I add Portrait mode feature while capture an image using custom camera.

Anyone please help me ..
I am using AVPhotoCapture were I had enable image depth property to true but there no portrait effect while capturing.

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Yes it's programming question. I need to integrate portrait mode in camera .

Answer (score -1):

Try installing google camera if your device has dual camera ,you can find the apk in apk mirror website. The Google camera has hdr mode and other focus modes,i hope it helps

Comment: OP is not on android.